# two components with same tcm id in tridion

Tags: 2011, sdl-tridion

I have modified component name,its document and publish it using SDL tridion.Now,on server its showing both component with same tcm id.

http://xxx.uu.com/Images/CrossBorderInsuranceGuidance-201505_tcm908-165451.pdf http://xxx.uu.com/Images/CrossBorderInsuranceGuidance_201410_tcm908-165451.pdf

I everytime modify my components like this only,but never cause such issue.

Could anyone please guide me on this asap?

Comment: This is quite surprising, given we go through quite some logic to prevent that you publish the same binary under 2 different names (as this will cause trouble when unpublishing). Could it be cached on your delivery server?

Answer (score 3):

There could be two reasons I can see:

- The component has been previously published with some Template code which appended an underscore (`_`), a month/year and the TCM ID to the file name. Now the same Template has been updated to append a dash (`-`), a month/year and the TCM ID of the file
- There are two Templates in place, one had published the Component with underscore and another one published with a dash

I would suggest, you should check your templates and its history of changes.

Comment: I have tried this multiple times before , my template works for both `-` and `_`. If this would have been issue, then I shouldn't be able to open both links (with `-` and `_`).

Answer (score 2):

You can publish the same multimedia component using different binary file names if you use a different variantId when publishing.

Maybe you should check your templates and review the methods you are using to publish binary files and if they use different variantId (AddBinary has several parameter sets, check TOM.NET API for details).

Comment: In addition to this, if you publishing these files as binary variants and you do not specify a related component when you publish then the broker cannot count references to published content and therefore cannot cleanup those variants when they become unused.